# Angular2 bootstrap modal with child component

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, angular2-template, ng-bootstrap, ng-modal

I would like to use Ng Bootstrap Modal with a child component as the modal body.
I'm not sure how I would achieve this...

```
export class ParentComponent {
   @ViewChild("modal") private engineModal: TemplateRef<any>;
   dialog: NgbModalRef | null;

   constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

   openModal(): void {
      this.dialog = this.modalService.open(this.engineModal);
   }

   cancelModal (): void {
      if ( this.dialog ) {
         this.dialog.dismiss();
         this.dialog = null;
      }
   }
}
```

and, I know this is wrong, but ultimately I'd like to do something like this,

```
<ng-template #modal>
  <app-child-component></app-child-component>
</ng-template>
```

Child component has a lot of Input and Output variables, so what whould be the best approach here?

Comment: you want to pass the `body` dynamically?

Comment: yes, that pretty much sums up what I would like to do

Comment: Go to https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples, and look at the second example, "Components as content".

Answer (score 1):

You may try content projection (transclusion for those familiar with AngularJS).

You can create a custom modal like this:

```
<div class="modal-body"> 
  <ng-content select="child-body"></ng-content>
</div>
```

And you create the child modal based on this custom-modal

```
<custom-modal>
  <child-body>
     {...}
  </child-body>
</custom-modal>
```

Basically what you write at between the child-body tags it will be copied in your custom-modal element at the ng-content's location.

Read more about content projection here:

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/projection.html

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hello yes you are right you have to use ViewChild to do this, then create an open function that use the open function as described :

```
open(engineModal) {
   console.log(this.engineModal) // global modal info from ViewChild
   console.log(engineModal) // modal info used for the function
   this.modalService.open(engineModal).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
   }, (reason) => {
   this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
});
```

See the .ts example https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

You simply have to do this, and you can now play with your modal

**EDIT: To access your child component inside your ng-template : // bad way**

```
@ViewChild(AppChildComponent) appChildComponent: AppChildComponent
this.engineModal.appChildComponent.function()
```

=> I would personally encapsulate the ng-template inside the ModalInfoComponent, ModalNewsComponent html and use directly my answer ;)

Comment: Well, I don't think this works tho, I'm trying to load the modal dynamically, and it's using the ng template.....

Comment: What about encapsulating you ng-template inside your own component ? Then you can have access to your component and the modal. So that you can rewrite the behavior of your child modal. is that what you need ?

Comment: I think that would be the best way, what do you mean by encapsulating the ng-template inside the component?

Comment: I mean you create your component with your input, output... and inside you'll have your ng-template ;) like this <app-modal-info (open)="open()" [title]="My title">
<ng-template #modal>specific html goes here</ng-template>
</app-modal-info>

Answer (score 0):

You can project the content by passing it as a input property

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(element.innerHTML)">Launch demo modal</button>
<div #element style="display:none">>
  SOME THING PROJECTED
</div>
```

Your modal component should have the below `modal-body`

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div [innerHTML]="modalBody">
  </div>
</div>
```

with the below input property

```
@Input() modalBody:string;
```

Update 1 : To change the values of `@Input()` property in the parent can be done as below,

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    this.modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'Opened After sometime';
},1000)
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/YSjgxWcPX2lGXaVOLQw2?p=preview)**

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I was just wondering if there's a way to load the child component since child component has interactions with the parent

Comment: by `load the child component` what you mean ? can you explain

Comment: Seems like I'm having to create a modal component. I mean which is fine, but then I already have child component defined where it takes about 12 inputs from parent component and have 4 eventemitter outputs. I can have them go through the modal component, but I'm wondering if there's any other way

Comment: @PowerLove so you don't want to load the modal dynamically?

Comment: I guess I kinda left out a lot of details in the question... I'm sorry, so the variables in the parent component dynamically changes, which changes the inputs in the child component

Comment: @PowerLove it will work if the variables are changed also